# Mismatch of text in drop down list and textbox text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have **drop down list** and a **text box**.

I am selecting an item from dropdownlist and on selection the selected text from dropdownlist is shown in textbox.

I am facing a problem here as below :

One of the text populated in dropdownlist is :

```
SUNROOF, POWER, TILT-SLIDING, ELECTRIC with express-open and wind deflector -Includes (CJ2) Air conditioning, dual-zone, automatic.  -Includes (ZM9) Universal Transmitter)
```

But when this is selected and the same text shown in textbox, the text is becoming as below .. i.e losing a space, and this is causing a problem.

```
SUNROOF, POWER, TILT-SLIDING, ELECTRIC with express-open and wind deflector -Includes (CJ2) Air conditioning, dual-zone, automatic. -Includes (ZM9) Universal Transmitter)
```

NOTE :  "automatic.[2space here]-Includes" in dropdownlist and "automatic.[1 space here]-Includes" in textbox. i.e. one space less.

Texts are loaded to the drop downlist like below :

```
ddlEngine.Items.Add(new ListItem(Engine[i][0], Engine[i][1]));
```

Here Engine[i][0] = TEXT

Engine[i][1] = Integer value for diff purpose..

And on change of dropdownlist value...the text is copied to the textbox as below :

```
document.getElementById("engineText").value = document.getElementById("ddlEngine").options[document.getElementById("ddlEngine").selectedIndex].text;
```

I need both of these values to be same.
Any idea why is this happening so??? And how can I get it of this behaviour.

Comment: Why would you be trying to populate a dropdown list with that much text to begin with James..?

Comment: ok that makes sense then.. so where or how are the values being populated in the dropdownlist..? do you have access to the code perhaps you can show how it's being loaded..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE .. Please see the edit once..I have added the code needed..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it and after this in codebehind:

```
ddl1.Items.Add("12        34")
```

the text appeared "12 34" in the dropdownlist on the page.

If it's feasible, you could convert all multiple spaces to a single space before adding the strings to the dropdownlist.

Another approach would be to use ddlEngine.SelectedIndex to copy the original, something like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = Engine[ddlEngine.SelectedIndex][0]
```

Comment: Definitely I will have to go for the approach you suggested...Is there no other way to address this?

Comment: Maybe you could use ddlEngine.SelectedIndex to copy the original?  Something like `textbox.text = Engine[ddlEngine.SelectedIndex][0]`  (I edited the answer to show this better.)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to confirm whether both of your controls are asp.net controls?

I just copied your code and executed. It is working fine for me.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="1108px" AutoPostBack="True"
            onchange="changeCursor()" Height="26px">
     <asp:ListItem>SUNROOF, POWER, TILT-SLIDING, ELECTRIC with express-open and wind deflector -Includes (CJ2) Air conditioning, dual-zone, automatic.  -Includes (ZM9) Universal Transmitter)</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="1103px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Following is the javascript function to show selected value-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function changeCursor() {
        document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = document.getElementById("DropDownList1").options[document.getElementById("DropDownList1").selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
```

are you using the same way????

Comment: Drop down list `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEngine" width="300" CssClass="textboxda" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"  onmousewheel="return false;" />`
Text box 
`<asp:textbox ID="engineText" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true" Rows="4" height="50px" Columns="56" CssClass="textboxda" runat="server" />`

Comment: Yes..It is the same way..But I am getting a space removed when the text is loaded in text box...

Comment: where are you writing document.getElementById("engineText").value = document.getElementById("ddlEngine").options[document.getElementById("ddlEngine").selectedIndex].text;

Comment: I think the space is removed when it is added to the dropdown list.